# What file system does ceph use for its OSDs

Tags: object, storage, ceph

everyone.

According to Sage A. Weil's paper, Ceph was using EBOFS as the file system for its OSDs. However, I looked into the source code of Ceph and could hardly find any code of EBOFS. Is Ceph still using EBOFS or has opted to use other types of file system for a single OSB?

Thank you:-)

Answer (score 2):

The EBOFS was deprecated many years ago.
then the default fs for osd filestore backend is btrfs for years,
bc the btrfs is not stable that time,
ceph community change it to xfs as deafult fs until now.

The filestore layer was aimed to HDD
Now community developed a new objectstore layer named bluestore,
which is designed for high speed storage disk like SSD